# phonegap/cordova local notification plugin how i display notification in a specific date and time?

Tags: sencha-touch-2, phonegap-plugins, cordova-3, localnotification

I am working in sencha touch and now I want to use the local notification in my project so I used this plugin for the local notification.

https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-local-notifications

the problem that I face is just that I can't display my notification on a specific time and date. It shows immediately the notification as i clicked on the action button so please help me out from this problem.

Comment: Can you provide a use case ? Why do you need to delay the apparition of the notification ? It seems more like a design flaw, notifications are not meant to be delayed, they are used to react to an event.

Comment: i want to display a notification as a medicine reminder which the user insert time at that time n date i would like to display my notification alert i don't think so any design flaw is here

Comment: It's not a design flaw, but what you want is an event that fire the notification at the right time, not the notification that display by itself at your time.

Comment: What I mean is you need something called Alarms in Android : http://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/alarms.html
Unfortunately it seems there are no equivalents in Sencha.

Comment: yess i want the notification that display by itself at user input time have you see this plugin

Comment: You will be better off using push notifications: https://github.com/phonegap-build/PushPlugin

Comment: For a medicine reminder ? It's local, and what about if there are no internet connection ? 
I'm sorry but i don't think it's a good idea, and anyway there is no plugin for delaying a task in sencha/cordova.

Comment: @JefferyAWooden yes i want just it locally no internet connection is required..

Comment: you can give the specific time in date object. window.plugin.notification.local.add({date: __ });

Answer (score 0):

The example below should work. I tested it myself. Be aware that if the date is in the past according to your phone the notification will pop up directly after you have set the notification.

```js
var beginTime = new Date('2016', '0', '12', '12', '45'); 
//year 
//month - 1 (month starts at 0 so you have 0-11)
//day
//hour
//minutes

cordova.plugins.notification.local.schedule({
    id: 1,
    title: 'Hello World',
    text: 'My first notification',        
    at: beginTime        
})
```